# rails server Error : yld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hello stack community,

I'm new to stackoverflow and new to Ruby on Rails. I went ahead and installed Ruby, Gems, and Rails on my mac.

I'm trying to do this tutorial working Ruby on Rails and in my terminal when I input:

> @ rails server

I get this error:

> $ rails server dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   _mysql_get_client_info   Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>   Expected in: flat namespace
>
> Trace/BPT trap

I have no idea what this means or what to do. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of mysql2 try another gem ruby-mysql. This might work in your case.